# Замена отсутствующих данных на медианные значения групп

Tags: python, pandas

Надо: подставить медианные значения каждой группы income_type на место пропусков в столбце total_income.

[image: Есть df по двум колонкам. total_income income_type]

были найдены медианные значения для каждой уникальной группы

```
data.groupby('income_type')['total_income'].median().round()
```

В столбце total_income есть отсутствующие значения, которые нужно заменить на медианное значение, для каждой группы.

Мной был выполнен код

```
def total_income_med(total_income):
    income_type = data['income_type']
    if income_type == 'сотрудник':
        return total_income == 142594.0
    if income_type == 'пенсионер':
        return total_income == 118514.0
    if income_type == 'компаньон':
        return total_income == 172358.0
    if income_type == 'госслужащий':
        return total_income == 150448.0
    if income_type == 'безработный':
        return total_income == 131340.0
    if income_type == 'предприниматель':
        return total_income == 499163.0
    if income_type == 'студент':
        return total_income == 98202.0
    if income_type == 'в декрете':
        return total_income == 53829.0

data['total_income'] = data['total_income'].fillna(total_income_med)
```

Но, почему-то при проверке типа данных у столбца выдает object.

Не могу понять, что именно я делаю не так. И возможно есть другой метод, который намного проще. Я только вторую неделю изучаю python :)

Comment: А до `fillna` какой тип данных был у столбца? Может он до того был уже `object`? А может у вас там кроме цифр есть ещё какие-то значения, которые не приводятся к цифровым? Часто бывает достаточно посмотреть `data['total_income'].value_counts()` чтобы увидеть что-то необычное.

Answer (score 0):

не уверен, что правильно понял, но возможно это вам поможет:

```
data.groupby('income_type').apply(lambda x: x['total_income'].fillna(x['total_income'].median()))
```

Answer (score 0):

По документации, в метод `.fillna` передается `scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame`, но не функция. Когда Вы в метод `.fillna` передаете функцию, по уму, надо было бы поднимать исключение `TypeError`, но это вопрос к разработчикам. Сейчас же, получается так, что Ваш код заменяет пропуски на `function total_income_med`, а не возвращаемым ей значением. Именно поэтому этот столбец датафрейма приобретает тип `object`.

Первый шаг был верный - делаем серию из медианных значений:

```
median_series = data.groupby('income_type')['total_income'].median().round()
```

Мы получили серию, которую можем передать в `.fillna`, но, предварительно, нам надо поставить в индекс исходного датафрейма значения из столбца `income_type`. Тогда метод `.fillna` будет брать индекс исходного датафрейма (то есть название группы) и подставлять значение из сгруппированной серии, в соответствие с этим индексом.

```
data['total_income'] = data.set_index('income_type')['total_income'].fillna(median_series)
```